# echo the value from HTML tag?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm beginner at PHP and Javascript so I think it's a stupid question. I have search but can't find the answer.
How can I echo the value from id's HMTL tag?

Ex: `<div id="test">Test</div>`

`<?php echo id?>` ???

Echo the id's value?

I get the id's value from javascript

```
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "abc";
```

Comment: Use a parser, if you have the HTML in PHP. It's unclear to me if JS is build your HTML here.

Comment: I think you need to know that PHP runs ONLY on the server while this javascript runs only on the browser